# automatic keyword generation evaluation

Tags: nlp, text-mining

I have a simple text analyzer with generates keywords for a given input text. Until now I have been doing a manual evaluation of it, i.e., manually selecting keywords of a text and comparing them against the ones generated by the analyzer.

Is there any way in which I can automate this? I tried googling a lot for some free keyword generators which can help in this evaluation but have not found any till now. I will appreciate any suggestions on how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Testing keyword generation is  a difficult problem. In the past, I have used the following method to evaluate it.

1. Identify the popular association-rule generation methods like Confidence, Jaccard, Lift, Chi-Squared, Mutual Information etc. There are many papers that compare such measures.
2. Implementing these measures is fairly simple. They all involve some simple algebraic expression using one or more of term frequencies, document frequencies and co-occurrence frequencies.
3. Generate related keywords using all of these measures and compute their union. Call this set TOTAL.
4. Compute the intersection of the keywords generated by your algorithm with the above TOTAL-set. When viewed as a fraction (intersection/TOTAL), it is a rough indicator of how powerful your measure is.

Comment: How do association rule methods apply to keyword generation? There aren't really rules guiding keyword identification as I understand it (I'm using pagerank, and identifying keywords for a given document in a corpus).

Comment: It's been several years  and I don't recall everything but you can use association rule methods to measure "termhood", i.e., if a given unigram / ngram is considered a 'term' or not. You will require a background corpus to determine some frequency statistics. Back when I answered the question in 2012, [this](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P05-1075) used to be the state of art method for identifying phrasal terms. [This paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W09-2905.pdf) outlines the various popular measures.

Answer (score 0):

I found an automatic keyword generation evaluation tool Text Mechanic's [Keyword Suggestion Generator](http://textmechanic.co/Keyword-Suggestion-Generator.html), which might help.

It says:

> The Text Mechanic's "Keyword Suggestion Generator" will retrieve Google.com auto suggest results* for your entered seed text in an easy to investegate format. Seed text can be a letter, number, word, phrase, related to what you (and others) are querying to find in Google search results.

I believe it can be automated.